# KMM - Privacy friendly file attribute APIs

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform

So Apple is starting to require declaration when using some APIs that can be used to fingerprint users. I've got a Kotlin Multiplatform library that I use that I think is triggering their `NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp` enforcement. I've got the following code which retrieves all the attributes of a file just to check if the file size exceeds a threshold (before we roll-over to a separate file).

```
private fun canWrite(): Boolean {
    val filePath = "$folder/$file"
    if (file == null || !NSFileManager.defaultManager.fileExistsAtPath(filePath)) {
        return false
    }

    val attr: Map<Any?, *>? = NSFileManager.defaultManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, null)
    if (attr == null || attr.isEmpty()) {
        return false
    }

    val fileSize = attr[NSFileSize] as Long
    return fileSize < maxFileSize
}
```

I guess `attributesOfItemAtPath()` is doing a `getAttrList()` in the background, which [Apple documents as getting flagged by this check](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api#4278393). I know that I can just declare this as a legitimate use of the API, but I really don't need everything else that comes back from an attribute list, I only care about the file size. Is there a better method I could use? All the examples I can find online just use `attributesOfItemAtPath` without a care and pre-date the privacy disclosures from Apple.

Comment: Just declare `C617.1` and move on